# Critical Error - Unable to get property 'strFormId'

Tags: web-part, infopath, error, custom-form

I have a site page that has 2 web parts.
   1. Sharepoint list passing form data to #2
   2. read-only Infopath form

The purpose of the page is to display list data

the issue that i am having is that the page works as expected but when I try to edit the page, i get the error below

[image]

Any ideas on what the issue can be and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so form is giving you a headache.Maybe that will work: Go to the web part maintenance (add to the url '?Contents=1' at the end) page and disable the IP webpart. Then you should be able to edit the page, make the changes you need and as a last part re-add the IP form.